# Install or Configure Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, office-2013

Situation: I have web application in my pc, who manipulates docs to generate pdfs with no problem. I configured my dcomcnfg to work fine because I had the problem with access permissions the COM.

The problem: I have to put the website in the server. The server has Win8 Enterprise. Doesn't have Visual Studio installed, only framework 4.0 and the Word Office. When I try to generate pdf it always return this error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ...
I run dcomcnfg and customized all permissions to IIS service (doesn't work and put to) Everyone. I Set all Launch and Activation permissions to allow Everyone, I also set Access Permissions and configuration permissions.. And still don't work.

- I have to register the dll in server?(How I do it?)
- I need more configurations?
- I Have to install all Office?

ps: Office 2013

Comment: It is a VERY, VERY BAD IDEA to use Office.Interop components on a web server.  Microsoft strongly recommends against it (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), and I can tell you from painful experience on several apps that I inherited years ago, using Office Interop in general is asking for trouble.  You're far better off using a 3rd party component designed for such work.

Comment: Could you try using something like this? http://nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words

Comment: Yes, you would need to install Word on the web server - but please don't..

Comment: Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Comment: There's a list of 3rd party vendors that secialize in creating/manipulating Office documents from the server safely, buried in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211835/the-best-3rd-party-component-for-generating-excel-spreadsheets-from-asp-net

Comment: @G_P is that component paid?

Comment: You're lucky. The kind of problem you're seeing now frequently doesn't appear until the application is in production and you're depending on it. Take this opportunity to use a different solution that will not cause bugs that are hard to reproduce and harder to fix.

Comment: @user1546424 I believe so, yes. Go to the "project site" link on the left side of the NuGet Gallery page there should be more info there...

Comment: There is no 3rd party component free??

Answer (score 0):

while it is not recommended to use this on server, there is a possible solution:

impersonate the admin in the asp.net application:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

- it may have security issue.